# Passing table name and field name as strings to function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with many tables and I am trying to check a given table for Null values. Rather than writing a function for each table I am attempting to pass the table name and field name as strings to one function (so that one function works on all tables).

I am able accomplish this with the table name but not with the field name. I recieve a runtime error of "Item not found in this collection"

```
Public myDb As DAO.Database
Public myTable As DAO.Recordset

Public Sub verifyFields()
    checkNull "Table Name", "Field Name"
End Sub


Public Sub checkNull(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fieldName As String)

    Set myDb = CurrentDb
    '============
    'Table Name | 'Check if Column "Field Name" for null values
    '============
    Set myTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tableName)
    myTable.MoveFirst
    Do Until myTable.EOF
        If IsNull(myTable![ & fieldName & ]) Then'<--Error is thrown here
            x = x + 1
            blanksFound = True
        End If
        myTable.MoveNext
    Loop
    If blanksFound = True Then
        aaa = MsgBox(x & " Blanks found.", vbOKOnly, blankField.Name)
    End If
```

The locals window shows that both strings were passed, but I still get the runtime error. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use variables in these cases, you use parentheses:

```
If IsNull(myTable(fieldName)) Then
```

But note that a more efficient way is to use a query:

```
x = DCount("*", tableName, "[" & fieldName & "] IS NULL")
```

Comment: Thank you both worked! And you're right, I think I will stick with the second example

Answer (score 2):

```
foo!bar
```

This notation is "bang notation". The `bar` part *looks* like a normal identifier, but to VBA it's a string literal - that's why you can't do this:

```
If IsNull(myTable![ & fieldName & ]) Then
```

Bang notation `foo!bar` is the equivalent of `foo.DefaultItemPropertyWithStringIndexer("bar").DefaultProperty`. So:

```
If IsNull(myTable.Fields(fieldName).Value) Then
```

Should work just fine. The shorter `myTable(fieldName)` notation is exactly the same, except with all these explicit member calls made implicit. I personally prefer code that *says what it does*, and *does what it says*.

As far as Access goes however, [using a query to query a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51409192/1188513) is the way to go.